# JobService after on destroyed keep app process running

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I create a UploadContactsJobService that extend JobService after uploading finish I called stopCurrentJob method

```
  private void stopCurrentJob() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            JOB_INFO = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,
                    new ComponentName(RDApp.get(), UploadContactsJobService.class))
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                    .addTriggerContentUri(
                            new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(CONTACTS_URI,
                                    JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS))
                    .build();
            scheduleJob(this);
        }
            jobFinished(mRunningParams, false);
    }
```

the Service destroyed but the application process is still running and the app still running in the background i notice this on Android Studio it , should I kill app process to prevent battery drain using this

```
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: `Service destroyed but the application process is still running and the app still running in the background` That's natural behavior, if your app is in background that's mean your app process is running in back ground, when the user clear your app from **recent apps** your app process will killed.

Comment: these services start when user add or update any contacts even the app is closed so the app will not be on recent apps

Comment: Thus `jobFinished(mRunningParams, true);` the 2nd param should be true instead to be  rescheduled according to the back-off criteria specified at schedule-time. otherwise: you need to debug your service lifecycle.

Comment: I log my service. UploadContactsJobService: on stop job
                           UploadContactsJobService: myService destroyed
and i think the service is destroyed  but still running